# How can I log into Draw Something if I have forgotten my username and email?

Tags: draw-something

I logged out of the game and now I lost my account but I do remember my email and username.

I don't remember putting in a password when I originally started off.

How can I recover my account?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like [you aren't the only one with this issue](http://forums.omgpop.com/omgpop-support/11906-draw-something-wont-let-me-login-e-mail.html) as they do not have a password recovery system set in place [yet].

From what I have found, your best option would be to contact their support at:

> feedback@omgpop.com

or create a new account.

Answer (score 2):

Try an email that you may have used, and there is a forgot password option.  They will email you the reset password which you can then use to login.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is press create account or something at the homepage, then put in your email.if you forgot your email, then that's inconvenient. Later, it will tell you to put in your password, if your forgot that, click forgot password, then it will email you the password and you can use that to put in.

You can also change once you log in to your account.

Comment: I meant click on email, then just put in the email, not username, then it will make you put in your password

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You can edit your answer by clicking "edit" under the body of the answer.