# Is there a way to link accounts for Draw Something?

Tags: draw-something

My mom just got an iPad for Mother's Day and wanted to know if it was possible to use the same account that she already had on her Android phone with her new iPad. I tried to set it up that way, but unfortunately it created a new account instead of using her old one. She really doesn't want to have to go through the pain of getting all those coins/bombs/color packages back again, and I don't blame her. Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Does it give you the option to 'sign in' when you first downloaded the app? If not, then most likely the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/61334/1561) deals with recovering a lost username and/or password. So you could delete Draw Something from the iPad and re-download it, and then enter in her existing account details.

Another option might be to link the Android Draw Something to a Facebook account, and then link the iPad Draw Something to the Facebook account as well. I've done this for my iPhone and iPad and it does a good job of keeping them in sync.