# Draw Something is not sending my password to my email

Tags: draw-something

I have forgotten my password for Draw Something, so I have followed the instructions to get my password reset and emailed to me and I received a message stating "your password has been sent" but it hasn't come through to my email - it's not in the spam folder either.

It has worked for me in the past using this method. I have deleted the app, restarted my iPhone and then downloaded it again but this hasn't resolved the problem.

Any ideas on how I can reset my password?

Comment: This might be a silly suggestion but did you try looking in the the spam folder of your email?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not receiving an email using the password reset feature in the game, then it might be worthwhile emailing their support directly using the following email address [as per this question regarding resetting passwords](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/61334/27134);

```
feedback@omgpop.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your spam inbox.  I was having this issue and tried the "forgot password" link several times and finally realized that the messages were being sent to spam. Very annoying and it took a message from Words with Friends to figure it out. They really need to work on this...oh well, disaster averted.