# How can I recover my password?

Tags: draw-something

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I log into Draw Something if I have forgotten my username and email?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61334/how-can-i-log-into-draw-something-if-i-have-forgotten-my-username-and-email)

I forgot my password because last year my iPad got locked, and my brother had to reset it.  That erased the game, and I have since forgotten my password.  Is there any way for me to retrieve it?

Comment: THanks for the information. What's the question? If your question was 'how to get the game back', try syncing with iTunes. This really has marginally to do with gaming. It belongs to superusers or ask different.

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting close votes.